# Separating Axis Theorem Duplicate Axis

Tags: separating-axis-theorem

I am building a physics game engine from the ground up and currently stumped with my SAT implementation. The situation I am having is in regard to Edge cases, if I remove all parallel / duplicate Axis from the possible 15, I run the risk of removing an edge case as seen in the attached photo.

[image: The edge pairs in this situation are parallel to the faces of the big blue cube]
Hoping you guys can give me some pointers, Thanks!

edit: I should state that the way I have my SAT implemented is I have 0-5 cases being the Face contact and 6 - 14 being Edge cases. When I dont remove parallel cases, situations such as the picture below get treated as an edge case

[image: the smaller cube is touching the bigger cubes face but it is detected as an edge contact]

edit: Probably shouldve added this in the beginning but here is the code where I am establishing my Axes to test.

The GetAxisFromEdge function simply takes two vectors and crosses them

The RemoveParralels function loops through the established axis and removes them if there exists a duplicate.

The FixAxes function is something of a patch to fix a greater problem where I needed the axis to face in the direction of one object for uniformity.

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> AxesToTest;


        glm::vec3 Obj1Edge1, Obj1Edge2, Obj1Edge3, Obj2Edge1, Obj2Edge2, Obj2Edge3;

        Obj1Edge1 = glm::normalize(this->Objects[x]->TransformedPhysMesh[1] - this->Objects[x]->TransformedPhysMesh[0]);
        Obj1Edge2 = glm::normalize(this->Objects[x]->TransformedPhysMesh[1] - this->Objects[x]->TransformedPhysMesh[2]);
        Obj1Edge3 = glm::normalize(this->Objects[x]->TransformedPhysMesh[1] - this->Objects[x]->TransformedPhysMesh[5]);

        Obj2Edge1 = glm::normalize(this->Objects[y]->TransformedPhysMesh[1] - this->Objects[y]->TransformedPhysMesh[0]);
        Obj2Edge2 = glm::normalize(this->Objects[y]->TransformedPhysMesh[1] - this->Objects[y]->TransformedPhysMesh[2]);
        Obj2Edge3 = glm::normalize(this->Objects[y]->TransformedPhysMesh[1] - this->Objects[y]->TransformedPhysMesh[5]);


        AxesToTest.push_back(this->Objects[x]->TransformedNormals[0]);
        AxesToTest.push_back(this->Objects[x]->TransformedNormals[1]);
        AxesToTest.push_back(this->Objects[x]->TransformedNormals[2]);

        AxesToTest.push_back(this->Objects[y]->TransformedNormals[0]);
        AxesToTest.push_back(this->Objects[y]->TransformedNormals[1]);
        AxesToTest.push_back(this->Objects[y]->TransformedNormals[2]);

        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge1, Obj2Edge1)));
        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge1, Obj2Edge2)));
        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge1, Obj2Edge3)));

        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge2, Obj2Edge1)));
        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge2, Obj2Edge2)));
        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge2, Obj2Edge3)));

        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge3, Obj2Edge1)));
        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge3, Obj2Edge2)));
        AxesToTest.push_back(glm::normalize(GetAxisFromEdges(Obj1Edge3, Obj2Edge3)));

        glm::vec3 toCenter = this->Objects[x]->Position - this->Objects[y]->Position;

        RemoveParallels(AxesToTest);
        //FixAxes(AxesToTest, toCenter);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "removing an edge case"? And how do you manage to remove something if you only remove it's duplicate?

Comment: By removing an edge case I mean one of the 9 edge pairs cross product that represents the the collision case between the two edges. Also, the way I have my SAT set up is that the first 6 cases are Face contacts, the rest are the edges, so what could happen is I have an edge case say at case 9 (Edge) which is parallel to case 3 (Face). When I remove case 9 I will still have case 3 but wont have an indicator that there has been and edge collision

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. You are supposed to remove duplicating axes. Axes are calculated from face normals. Are you removing actual faces instead of resulting normals?

Comment: Yea the first 6 axes are the face normals of object A and object B, the way I am calculating the remaining 9 cases is by crossing the 3 faces of A with the 3 faces of B. So what I am removing is the resulting normals

Comment: Removing faces makes no sense. Faces being parallel does not cancel the fact that faces' vertices have different coordinates, resulting in different projection outcome.

Comment: So when you say you are suppose to remove duplicates, what do you mean? I understood that as removing axis that are parallel. Also im not removing the Face cases (0-5) I am bias removing the edge cases (6-14).

Comment: You might want to show us your code, so there's no ambiguity about what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry guys shouldve did that to prevent any confusion, I appreciate your help!